# Can I carry soldering station from India to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items

I am from India, travelling to Frankfurt for my Master's studies. Would I be able to take my soldering station and few circuits and evaluation modules in checked in baggage? Will there be any problems at Customs when I arrive?

Comment: It's worth noting that soldering equipment can be purchased very cheaply in Germany, and if you're entering into a master's program related to circuitry, your university will almost certainly provide you with the necessary equipment.

Comment: As per my knowledge soldering station is not that cheap and I think it is better to carry my trusted station than buying some cheap soldering irons instead of station. College may provide it in labs but I also need it for my personal projects.

Comment: fair enough! You know your situation better than I, of course.  But, if you want to check it out: https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/258-5596153-8347164?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=solder

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion, but I was referring to something like this https://www.amazon.de/Velleman-L%C3%B6tstation-keramisch-L%C3%B6tschwamm-VTSSC50N/dp/B0016MBRDA/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1503854497&sr=8-4&keywords=soldering+station

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem at all. I had about a dozen evaluation boards in my checked luggage last week and it was not even opened by the TSA. The solder station itself (assuming a conventional mains-powered solder station) is just an inert appliance with no internal power source.

Rolls of solder may pose an inconvenience, especially on your return to India, as they may look like you are smuggling precious metal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! I won't be returning to India soon as I am going there for my master studies. But will the solder rolls not cause any problems  while I arrive there?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if you had the non-RoHS solder (eg. Sn63/Pb37) I don't see that it's specifically [prohibited or restricted](http://crossborder.fedex.com/us/assets/prohibited-restricted/germany/index.shtml).